# Closed expression for the sum $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Studying and proving the interesting formula 1.439.2 of Gradshteyn/Ryzhik,

$$\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=\prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{4}{3} \sin^2 \left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)\right)\tag{GR 1.439.2}$$

I came up with the following related question:

Define

$$f(x) = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)\tag{1}$$

Question 1: is there a closed expression for $f$ in terms of known functions?

Question 2: what are the properties of $f$ (singularities, periodicity, self similarity, asymptotic behavour)?

Here is a plot of the function

[image]

For the range up to $x=1000$ the plot is

[image]

It shows heavy oscillation about some weakly exhibited trend. This trend should be specified in the answer to question 2.

*Generalizations*

One obvious generalization is to take other powers $p$ of $\sin$ under the sum

$$f_p(x) = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sin^p \left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)\tag{2}$$

Another one replaces $3$ by a parameter $a$.

$$f_p(x,a) = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sin^p \left(\frac{x}{a^k}\right)\tag{3}$$

Comment: How can the function ever go negative, it being a sum of *squares*?

Comment: @ Barry Cipra Never, you are right. The plot with negative values was done with $\sin$ rather than with $\sin^2$. I have corrected the statements of my question.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the formula 1.439.2 of Gradshteyn/Ryzhik, since not everyone has access to the book? Then it will be more clear where does this series come from

Comment: Concerning your last series: $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \exp \left(\frac{x}{a^k}\right)$$ do you remember that $e^0=1$? I don't think the series converges

Comment: @ Yuriy Thank you. You are right, the series is divergent. I have removed that part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Introduction**

While question (1) most probably has a negative answer, i.e. the sum is neither itself a known function not is it expressible as a (finite) combination of known functions, there are some interesting results related to question (2) which I am going to describe in this solution.

We shall discuss the infinite sum

$$f(z,a,p) = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sin ^p\left(\frac{z}{a^k}\right)\tag{1}$$

where $a \gt 1$, $p = 1, 2, 3, ...$ and $z$ is the argument which can be a complex number.

**Basic properties**

Unless stated otherwise we consider the analytic properties of $f$ as a function of the variable $x$ for given parameters $a$ (real, $\gt 1$) and $p$ (positive integer). $x$ can be a complex number.

1. The radius of convergence of the sum $f$ is infinite. Hence $f$ is an entire transcendental function, i.e. is has no singularities in the complex x-plane except for $x=\infty$. It admits a power series representation which, about $x=0$, is given in the section *Taylor series*.
2. Zeroes of *f* as a function of *x*
   For even $p$ there is only the trivial zero of $f$ at $x=0$; for odd $p$ there are real zeroes, even infinitely many (otherwise $f$ would be a polynomial). I conjecture that there are no zeroes beyond the real x-axis.
3. Periodicity
   $f$ is not periodic, i.e. there is no $d>0$ for which $f(x) = f(x+d)$ for all $x$.
4. Monotonity, boundedness
   $f$ is not monotonous. It is finite for any finite $x$; $f$ is not bounded for even $p \gt 0$ (see section *patterns, approximations and asymptotic behaviour*); it remains open if $f$ is bounded for odd $p$.
5. Functional equation
   As $f(x,a,p)$ is of the general form $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty g(\frac{x}{a^k})$
   (with $g(z)=\sin(z)^p$) it obeys the functional equation

$$f(a x) = f(x) + g(x)\tag{2}$$

**Patterns, approximations and asymptotic behaviour**

Let us first study the patterns exhibited in the plots of our function.

We shall start with the cases $p=1$ ($f(x)$ antisymmetric) and $p=2$ ($f(x)$ symmetric).

*p = 1*

Plot 1a:

[image]

Plot 1b:

[image]

Plot 1c:

[image]

*p = 2*

Plot 2a:

[image]

Plot 2b:

[image]

Plot 2c:

[image]

The overall pattern of the graphs of the function can be described as follows

1. "ups" and "downs" follow each other regularly, i.e. there are no "shoulders".
2. there is a "basic pattern" which for "p=1" looks like an inverted "w" follwed by a smaller inverted "v", and for "p=2" an inverted "w" with the central "v" flipped upwards. This basic pattern is repeated indefinitely at different "altitudes".
3. on a larger scale we see heavy fluctuations about a trend

In attempting to describe the trend I found it useful to consider the arithmetic mean of the function between $0$ and $x$ instead of the function itself.

Integrating the summand for $p=1$ and $p=2$ gives, respectively,

$$f_{m}(1)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \sin \left(\frac{t}{3^k}\right) \, dt = \frac{3^k}{x}  \left(1-\cos \left(3^{-k} x\right)\right)$$

$$f_{m}(2)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \sin ^2\left(\frac{t}{3^k}\right) \, dt=\frac{1}{4 x} \left(2 x-3^k \sin \left(2\ 3^{-k} x\right)\right)$$

Now, in addition, we consider another "smooting" method, we replace the k-sum by an integral, and consider two different expressions depending on the starting value of $k$ in the integral.

This leads to expresions designated $f_{m}(p,k_{0})$ where $m$ stands for "mean", "p" is the power $p$ and $k_{0}$ is the lower limit of the k-integral:

$$f_{m}(1,0)=\int_0^{\infty } f_{m}(1) \, dk=\frac{x \text{Si}(x)+\cos (x)-1}{x\log (3)}$$

$$f_{m}(1,1)=\int_1^{\infty } f_{m}(1) \, dk=\frac{x \text{Si}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+3 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-3}{x \log (3)}$$

$$f_{m}(2,0)=\int_0^{\infty } f_{m}(2) \, dk=\frac{2 x (-\text{Ci}(2 x)+\log (2 x)+\gamma -1)+\sin (2 x)}{x \log (81)}$$

$$f_{m}(2,1)=\int_1^{\infty } f_{m}(2) \, dk=\frac{2 x \left(-\text{Ci}\left(\frac{2 x}{3}\right)+\log \left(\frac{2 x}{3}\right)+\gamma -1\right)+3 \sin \left(\frac{2 x}{3}\right)}{x \log (81)}$$

We show now the plots for $p=1$ of the arithmetic mean of $f$ and the approximation replacing the k-sum by the integral for different ranges of $x$:

Plot 1ma:

[image]

Plot 1mb:

[image]

Plot 1mc:

[image]

Conclusions for $p=1$

1. The mean oscillates in a peculiar "sawtooth" manner about $f_{m}(1,1)$ which for large $x$ approaches $\pi / \log(9)$
2. There is a kind of self-similarity in the mean: the pattern roughly repeats in different scales. This can be traced back to the functionl euqation (2).

For $p=2$ we also show the two versions of the k-sums

[image]

[image]

[image]

Conclusions for $p=2$

1. the most prominent feature is that $f_{m}$ is enclosed between the two approximations differing in the lower limit of the k-integral
2. the self similarity of $p=1$ is also observed here, but less pronounced

**Taylor series**

Inspired by the idea of Yuriy S. I have calculated (with a different method) the Taylor series of $f$ for general powers $p$.

After inserting the series expansion of $\sin$, and doing the geometric series in $k$ the main task left is to calculate the multinomial sums of the type

$$\sum_{n_i\ge 0,\;r=\sum _{i=1}^p n_i} \frac{1}{\prod _{i=1}^p (2 n_i+1)!}\tag{t1}$$

and the result can be written in the form

$$f_T(z,a,p) = \sum _{r=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^r z^{p+2 r} d(p,r)}{(p+2 r)! \left(a^{p+2 r}-1\right)}\tag{t2}$$

where the first 9 coefficients $d(p,r)$ in the format $\{p,d(p,r)\}$ are

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \{1,1\} \\
 \left\{2,2^{2 r+1}\right\} \\
 \left\{3,\frac{3}{4} \left(9^{r+1}-1\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{4,2^{2 r+3} \left(4^{r+1}-1\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{5,\frac{5}{16} \left(-3^{2 r+5}+25^{r+2}+2\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{6,-3 2^{2 r+1} \left(2^{2 r+7}-3^{2 r+5}-5\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{7,\frac{7}{64} \left(-5^{2 r+7}+9^{r+4}+49^{r+3}-5\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{8,4^{r+2} \left(7\ 2^{2 r+7}+2^{4 r+13}-9^{r+4}-7\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{9,\frac{9}{256} \left(4\ 5^{2 r+9}-7^{2 r+9}-28\ 9^{r+4}+81^{r+4}+14\right)\right\} \\
\end{array}\tag{t3}
$$

This result provokes the desire to have the general formula for $d(p,r)$.

Up to now I could only see the factor $\frac{p}{2^{p-1}}$ for even $p$ but I was not able to identify the terms for odd $p$ and even less the structure of the "polynomials" in powers of some small numbers.

What I did find out up to now for the "polynomials" is

1. for even $p$ there is a term $p^{2r+p-1}$
2. the number of summands is $\left\lceil \frac{p}{2}\right\rceil$

Heureka! I found simple expressions after picking up a suggestion I found browsing through OEIS: the generating functions of the coefficients.

Defining

$$g(p, t) =\frac{1}{p!} \sum_{r=0}^\infty d(p,r) t^r\tag{t4}$$

explicit formulae for these sums are found easily, and we write down the expressions for $1/g$:

$$\frac{1}{g(p_{even},t)}=\prod _{m=1}^{\frac{p}{2}} \left(1-(2 m)^2 t\right)\\=(1-4t)(1-16t)(1-36t) ...(1-p^2 t)\\=(2 i)^p t^{p/2} \left(1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)_{\frac{p}{2}} \left(1+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)_{\frac{p}{2}}\tag{t5e}$$
$$\frac{1}{g(p_{odd}, t)}=\prod _{m=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left(1-(2 m+1)^2 t\right)\\= (1-t)(1-9t)(1-25t) ... (1-p^2 t)\\=(2 i)^{p-1} (1-t) t^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)_{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\right)_{\frac{p-1}{2}}\tag{t5o}$$

Here we have also expressed the finite products via the Pochhammer symbol defined as $(x)_k = x(x+1).. (x+k-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

While I doubt a closed form exists, we can rewrite the series in another form, specifically (I consider another generalization):

> $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin^2 \frac{x}{a^k}=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!~(a^{2n}-1)}$$

To find this form, consider the derivative:

$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{a^k} \sin \frac{x}{a^k} \cos \frac{x}{a^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a^k} \sin \frac{2x}{a^k}=$$

Using the Taylor series for $\sin$ we obtain:

$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{a^k} \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)! ~a^{k(2n+1)}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)! } \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a^{k(2n+2)}}=$$

Using the geometric series:

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!~(a^{2n+2}-1) }$$

We found the derivative, now we integrate by term, noting to fix the constant of integration, that:

$$f(0)=0$$

Since:

$$\int x^{2n+1}=\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2}$$

We have:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!~(a^{2n+2}-1) }=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!~(a^{2n}-1)}$$

This form is more useful, because it represents the Taylor series for the function $f(x)$.

Numerically, both the series converge very fast (provided $|a|>1$ of course), so from computational standpoint one is as good as the other, though the series derived here has a rational form.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find the Yuriy S' series, just for fun. Let $\mathfrak{M}\left(*,s\right)$ the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform). Using the identity $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\lambda_{k}g\left(\mu_{k}x\right),\,s\right)=\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\lambda_{k}}{\mu_{k}^{s}}\mathfrak{M}\left(g\left(x\right),s\right) $$ we have $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x}{3^{k}}\right),\,s\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}3^{ks}\mathfrak{M}\left(\sin^{2}\left(x\right),s\right)$$ and since $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sin^{2}\left(x\right),s\right)=-\Gamma\left(s\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)2^{-1-s}$$ we get $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\lambda_{k}g\left(\mu_{k}x\right),\,s\right)=\Gamma\left(s\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\frac{2^{-1-s}}{3^{-s}-1},\,-1<\mathrm{Re}\left(s\right)<0.$$ So, inverting, we get $$\sum_{k\geq1}\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x}{3^{k}}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-1/2-i\infty}^{-1/2+i\infty}\Gamma\left(s\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\frac{2^{-1-s}}{3^{-s}-1}x^{-s}ds.$$ It is not difficult to prove that, if $\mathrm{Re}\left(s\right)\rightarrow-\infty$, then the integral goes to $0$ so, observing that the integrand has poles at $s=-2n,\,n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$, by the residue theorem, we get $$\sum_{k\geq1}\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x}{3^{k}}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(2x\right)^{2n}}{\left(3^{2n}-1\right)\left(2n\right)!}}$$ as wanted. This method can easily generalized to a generic $\left|a\right|>1.$ Another observation: taking $$x=\frac{a}{2}$$ the series in red taking a form of a [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series).